# Redirect root to /path/ for single page application and NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a project use the subdomain as part of the request path for react SPA.

e.g. qem.xxx.com -> xxx.com/qem for a SPA where the file path doesn't change with the request.

I've been messing about for a while with rewrites but haven't been able to achieve it. Most of the resources seem to deal with the opposite, or with non-SPAs where the file path matches.

Here's the latest conf:

```
server {
  listen ${NGINX_PORT};
  server_name ${NGINX_HOST} 
  charset utf-8;
  client_max_body_size 20M;
  # what file to server as index
  root /src/build;
  index index.html index.htm;
  
  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance {
    root /src;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /deploy/maintenance.html break;
  }

  location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
    if (-f /src/maintenance.txt) {
                return 503;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ @qem /index.html;
  }
  
  location @qem {
    rewrite ^ /qem/$request_uri?;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

EDIT: Further details as requested:

1. NGINX_HOST=qem.xxx.com
2. Only one SPA application, so only one index.html in folder root
3. Have static resources that $uri and $uri/ match, all site content is served by index.html
4. Trying to achieve access to qem.xxx.com to serve as if the user accessed xxx.com/qem/ (i.e. this subdomain serves that part of SPA)

Currently semi-works in that it serves a blank page (200s).

Even just a general steer in the correct direction would be great!

Cheers,
Carl

Comment: Don't understand anything from your question. Does this `server` block supposed to serve both applications? What is that `${NGINX_HOST}` supposed to be? Are these applications have different `index.html` files? Where are those files physically located? Only the last parameter of `try_files` directive could be the location name, all the others are treating as filenames prepended with `$document_root` including your `@qem` parameter (that is, nginx is checking for `/src/build@qem` file existence).

Comment: Thanks for that - bit of a newb. Added some more notes to question that hopefully help describe what I was trying to achieve.

Comment: I can be wrong, I'm not familiar with React, but I think it is impossible, you can't alter React Router from server side. Maybe there is a way to inject some additional javascript to do it after the page load, but it looks like a dirty hack and if it ever exists it is beyond my knowledge. Someone who familiar with React and React-Router should say the final words about this subject.